# Git feature branches: Can I put them on a sub-directory

Tags: git

Is here a way in git to put my feature branches into a sub directory?
 Currently I wouldn't like to delete them, although many say there is no use in keeping them post merge operation.

So, if all the feature branches of all my team members are located under, for example,

> MyCompany/OurProject

I'd like my feature branches to be under

> MyCompany/OurProject/MyName

Note, I am not speaking only about new fb, but also about current ones.

Comment: Sorry in advance, this is only an observation, not a judgement BUT your question shows a profound misunderstanding of anything git. I'd suggest reading a few basic tutorials to get started, because your definitions seem very off. Branches weigh nothing, you could create a thousand of them and never notice. Also, "put" branches in a sub-dir? What for? Branches are not files.... Tell us more, I might be the one missing something in the picture.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you for your advise. There is always something to learn... Regarding your last question: when I look in my bitbucket view of project feature branches I see a long list if them, so I would have prefer to make the list shorter by unite common branches under some kind of a directory, node, whatever.

Comment: @duskin I get your point. Branch management is something to consider in git, yes. It's not really a size issue, rather workflow and clarity. Deleting obsolete (feature) branches is indeed something that needs to be done in some way or another. But moving files/directories is not the way to do that. Branches are just like variable names, lightweight pointers for naming purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you want bitbuckets to present the branches to you in a different way.  But it seems like what you really want is to simply not push your branches to bitbucket.  Or put a fork on bitbucket and keep all your branches there.  The level of granularity that you seem to want is best achieved in git by using different repositories, not different directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout MyCompany/OurProject/branch_name
git checkout -b MyCompany/OurProject/MyName/branch_name
git branch -D MyCompany/OurProject/branch_name
```

Comment: Thank you Vertexwahn. I guess I should add </branch_name> at the end of each command? For example: git checkout MyCompany/OurProject/my_feature_branch

Comment: Yes. Updated answer.